# creating driver on beaglebone black

Tags: makefile, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am trying to make a driver on beaglebone black, i am using Angstrom v2012.12 version. While i checked on /lib/modules/3.8.13 there is no folder build, so when i first run the command make it shows as no build directory after that just a try i made a build directory manually using mkdir build but after that also the issue is not resolved. please help me to figure out what is the actual problem in make command on beaglebone.

[image: error that showed in putty]

Comment: You have to install development tools and packages.

Comment: yes i did as follows `opkg update ,
opkg install task-native-sdk ,
opkg install kernel-headers ` then also not working and also i am adding my make file as follows `
obj-m+=test.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean`